# Hide UI components based on selected user usertype OIM

Tags: oim

I need to show the reset password button only if selected user usertype is 'External' , hide the reset password button if user usertype is 'Employee'.

used EL expression  #{!bindings.role.inputValue=='Employee'} to hide this button,  bindings.role.inputValue value itself coming as null, am I missing anything in regards to bindings or does it need to be implemented using custom managed bean ?

Thanks

Comment: check if not operator is creating a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of EL expression and check the current role of the loged in user. e.g.

```
#{oimcontext.currentUser.roles['SYSTEM ADMINISTRATORS'] != null}
```